# Partial Derivative notation in a context I don't recognise

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

I'm trying to follow a [document](http://www.acceleware.com/sites/default/files/Acceleware_SEG2010_CPML.pdf) describing a 'Perfectly Matched Layer' (an FDTD boundary condition), however it uses partial derivative notation in a context I'm not familiar with:

$$ \psi^n_i = a_i\psi^{n-1}_i + b_i\bigg(\frac{\partial}{\partial i}\bigg)^n $$

I don't know what the numerator-less partial derivative in the parentheses *is*, it appears to be partial derivative of *nothing* in respect to $i$.  The authors use partial-derivative-with-no-numerator notation in a context I'm more familiar with later on in the document:

$$ \frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial i^2} = \frac{\partial}{\partial i}\bigg(\frac{\partial P}{\partial i}\bigg)$$

I should point out that $i$ is a basis vector in 3D Cartesian space i.e. $i \epsilon \{x, y, z\}$.

As you may have realised, mathematics is not a strong subject of mine, but I'll try to answer any queries you have.

Comment: It's a *differential operator*. Consider “multiplying” a function $f$ on both sides of the equation to let it make sense to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an equality of operators. You have to apply it to some function $f$, like in

$$\psi^n_i f = a_i\psi^{n-1}_i f + b_i\bigg(\frac{\partial}{\partial i}\bigg)^n f = a_i\psi^{n-1}_i f + b_i \frac{\partial^n f}{\partial i^n}.$$

Comment: $\psi^n_i$ is only used in what I thought was a first order partial derivative scenario:  $\bigg(\frac{\partial \psi_i}{\partial i}\bigg)^n$. How does that relate to your $f$?  I've also added what $i$ actually is in the question, if that helps.

Comment: @cmannett85: I've taken a look at that article and I feel furious: the way those authors use the mathematical formalism is scandalous. Don't engineers study mathematics anymore these days? I am sorry, but it is impossible to tell what those authors want to do there; in particular, the equation in your question makes no sense.

Comment: Ha, I feel your pain! I have a feeling that $\frac{\partial}{\partial i}$ is actually just referring to a single grid interval (remember the paper is describing a boundary condition for an FDTD) along a single basis vector in 3D Cartesian space, i.e. one component of the 3D vector differential operator ($\nabla$).  What's really annoying for me is that all the equations are written in continuous form, whereas it's describing a mechanism that is only ever used discretized, so papers in this field end up using tortuous notation for often very simple concepts.